# ImprovedNamingStrategy no longer working in Hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-5.x

I have simple spring-jpa configuration where I have configured Hibernate's `ImprovedNamingStrategy`. This means if my entity class has a variable `userName`, then Hibernate should convert it to `user_name` for querying the database. But this naming conversion stopped working after I upgraded to Hibernate 5. I am getting the error:

> ERROR: Unknown column 'user0_.userName' in 'field list'

This is my Hibernate config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.springJpa.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("admin");
        return ds;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){ 

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.springJpa.entity");


        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy","org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");

        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SharedEntityManagerBean entityManager() {
        SharedEntityManagerBean entityManager = new SharedEntityManagerBean();
        entityManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return entityManager;
    }



    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ImprovedNamingStrategy namingStrategy(){
        return new ImprovedNamingStrategy();
    }
}
```

This is my Entity class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;

}
```

I don't want to explicitly name my database fields within the @Column annotations. I want my configuration which can implicitly convert camel case to underscore.

Please guide.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use @Column

Comment: @Tyler its just for ease of coding, adding "@Column" for each of variable is just annoying, instead i can configure Naming-Strategy which will map the variable name to db column names and i can avoid writing so many Column annotation

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Just figured out the issue, the configuration is absolutely fine when using a Hibernate version < 5.0 but not for Hibernate >= 5.0.

I was using Hibernate 5.0.0.Final with Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE. I guess the Hibernate 5 is not fully compatible with Spring 4.2 . I just downgraded Hibernate to 4.2.1.Final and things started working fine.

Hibernate's `NamingStrategy` class is deprecated in Hibernate 5.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is accepted and it has many negative votes!

Comment: That is because OP answered own question. It might have worked for the OP but the community thinks that either the approach taken by the OP is not correct or the answer provided by the OP is not a generic one.

Answer (score 78):

Thanks for posting your own solution. It helps me so much to set Hibernate 5 naming strategy!

The `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` property of pre-Hibernate 5.0 seems split into two parts:

- `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy`
- `hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy`

The values of these properties do not implement the `NamingStrategy` interface as did `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy`. There are two new interfaces for these purposes:

- `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy`
- `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy`

Hibernate 5 provides only one implementation of `PhysicalNamingStrategy` (`PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`) that assumes physical identifier names are the same as logical ones.

There are several implementations of `ImplicitNamingStrategy` but I found none equivalent to the old `ImprovedNamingStrategy`. (See: `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl`)

So, I implemented my own `PhysicalNamingStrategy` which is very simple:

```
public class PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl implements Serializable {

 public static final PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl INSTANCE = new PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl();

 @Override
 public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
     return new Identifier(addUnderscores(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
 }

 @Override
 public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
     return new Identifier(addUnderscores(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
 }


 protected static String addUnderscores(String name) {
     final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder( name.replace('.', '_') );
     for (int i=1; i<buf.length()-1; i++) {
        if (
             Character.isLowerCase( buf.charAt(i-1) ) &&
             Character.isUpperCase( buf.charAt(i) ) &&
             Character.isLowerCase( buf.charAt(i+1) )
         ) {
             buf.insert(i++, '_');
         }
     }
     return buf.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
 }
}
```

Note that the `addUnderscores()` method is from the original `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy`.

Then, I set this physical strategy into the persistence.xml file :

```
  <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="my.package.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl" />
```

It is a trap to set Hibernate 5 naming strategy as previous version settings.

Comment: Also, along with the custom physical naming strategy, the property `hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy` can be set to `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl`

Comment: Thanks @Samuel for explaining this and providing example for implementing ur own Naming_Strategy. Its helpful and even I am looking to implement similar Naming_Strategy

Comment: great answer Samuel, it deserves to be the correct one and not the other. Does anyone know why they changed this behavior? It makes to me no sense at all

Comment: Why do you add `implements Serializable` while the `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` already implements that?

Comment: Spring Boot 1.4 update: You can now use Spring's [SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.html) like this (yml):

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`

Comment: I don't think it is needed to touch the physical naming strategy, which will also override explicitly set column names. Just changing the implicit strategy (which is only applied when no explicit overrides are set) should be sufficient.
There is a default implicit naming strategy available, which prefixes embedded classes: `hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl`

See also the hibernate documentation for more details: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/naming.html

Answer (score 13):

Instead of

```
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",
                  "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
```

change to the new physical naming strategy and the new implementation `CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy`, which behaves as the old `ImprovedNamingStrategy`:

```
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy",
                  "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy");
```

Available in Hibernate 5.6.1.FINAL

Comment: Hopefully people make it down this far! This is by far the cleanest solution and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, just use `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` (because `CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy` is a copy of it. From docs: **"Originally copied from Spring Boot as this strategy is popular there (original name is SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy)"**. Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy.html

Answer (score 7):

*Thanks and +1 to Samuel Andrés for the very helpful answer*, however it's probably a good idea to avoid the hand-written snake-casing logic. Here is the same solution, using Guava.

It assumes your entity names are written in the `StandardJavaClassFormat` and column names in the `standardJavaFieldFormat`

Hopefully this will save some people coming here in future some googling :-)

```
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;
import static com.google.common.base.CaseFormat.*;

public class SnakeCaseNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

  public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
    return new Identifier(
      UPPER_CAMEL.to(LOWER_UNDERSCORE, name.getText()),
      name.isQuoted()
    );
  }

  public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
    return new Identifier(
      LOWER_CAMEL.to(LOWER_UNDERSCORE, name.getText()),
      name.isQuoted()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, though has some of its own flaws. For example, Hibernate's default discriminator column name is "DTYPE" which will get converted to "d_t_y_p_e".

Comment: @xathien thanks, was not aware of that. I guess a static mapping of special cases could be added to deal with things like this in a clear way

Answer (score 3):

thanks for that post. Little anoying that upgrade breaks the table and column name strategy. Instead of copying the logic from `ImprovedNamingStrategy` you could also  use delegation.

```
public class TableNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {
    private static final String TABLE_PREFIX = "APP_";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final ImprovedNamingStrategy STRATEGY_INSTANCE = new ImprovedNamingStrategy();

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(classToTableName(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(STRATEGY_INSTANCE.classToTableName(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
    }

    private String classToTableName(String className) {
        return STRATEGY_INSTANCE.classToTableName(TABLE_PREFIX + className);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's a clever idea. `ImprovedNamingStrategy` implements a deprecated interface. While only the interface `NamingStrategy` is explicitly marked deprecated I'd assume once that one is removed all implementing classes will be removed as well.

Comment: @MarcelStör -- I think that's a feature of this approach, not a bug! If and when Hibernate get around to replacing the old "ImprovedNamingStrategy", they will hopefully remove that deprecated class, and this code will break nosily, giving us a prompt to switch over to the new official implementation and to remove this workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Every answer posts solution by implementing `PhysicalNamingStrategy`, but all you need (and should do) is to implement `ImplicitNamingStrategy`.

> When an entity does not explicitly name the database table that it maps to, we need to implicitly determine that table name. Or when a particular attribute does not explicitly name the database column that it maps to, we need to implicitly determine that column name. There are examples of the role of the org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy contract to determine a logical name when the mapping did not provide an explicit name.

And the code can be as easy as this (using the original `addUnderscores` as in other answers):

```
public class ImplicitNamingStrategyImpl extends ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl {

    @Override
    protected Identifier toIdentifier(String stringForm, MetadataBuildingContext buildingContext) {
        return super.toIdentifier(addUnderscores(stringForm), buildingContext);
    }

    protected static String addUnderscores(String name) {
        final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(name.replace('.', '_'));
        for (int i = 1; i < buf.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i - 1))
                    && Character.isUpperCase(buf.charAt(i))
                    && Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i + 1))) {
                buf.insert(i++, '_');
            }
        }
        return buf.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps:

hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=....ImplicitNamingStrategy
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=....PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl

and here is the code (just re-arrenged from existing code):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl implements Serializable {

    public static final PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl INSTANCE = new PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl();

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(addUnderscores(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(addUnderscores(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
    }

    protected static String addUnderscores(String name) {
        final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder( name.replace('.', '_') );
        for (int i=1; i<buf.length()-1; i++) {
            if (
                Character.isLowerCase( buf.charAt(i-1) ) &&
                Character.isUpperCase( buf.charAt(i) ) &&
                Character.isLowerCase( buf.charAt(i+1) )
            ) {
                buf.insert(i++, '_');
            }
        }
        return buf.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No Guava and Apache utils

```
public class PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return context.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(
                name.getText().replaceAll("((?!^)[^_])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").toLowerCase(),
                name.isQuoted()
        );
    }

    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return context.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(
                name.getText().replaceAll("((?!^)[^_])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").toLowerCase(),
                name.isQuoted()
        );
    }
}
```