# Geometry DataType in H2 w/ Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jackson, postgis

**Context:**
I've been trying to get Geometry Datatypes working with H2 before I eventually move to PostgreSQL. My code compiles but when I attempt to retrieve the User model it fails because of Geometry location. I get a value too long for column "LOCATION BINARY(255): 'X'aced005...."

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./members.db
server.port = 8090
```

gradle.build, the main dependencies for this are the vividsolutions and some of the hibernate ones.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile (group: 'com.vividsolutions', name: 'jts', version: '1.13')
    compile (group: 'org.orbisgis', name: 'h2gis', version: '1.3.1')
    compile (group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.10.Final')
    compile (group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.2.10.Final')
    compile (group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '5.2.10.Final')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    //  runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
}
```

**Entity:** If I don't provide getters/setters for location the application runs but that's because it's not actually trying to access that data. I've tried using other annotations to define Geometry for location,         @Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
 [Hibernate spatial docs](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/02-Tutorial/01-tutorial4/). That annotation won't even compile because it doesn't recognize hibernate.spatial despite having the dependency in gradle.

```
package com.alex_donley.event_mapper.Entities;


import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by Indycorps on 5/11/2017.
 */
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Column(columnDefinition="Geometry")
    private Geometry location;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, Geometry location) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public User(){}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //Create getters and setters for location to actually output stuff

    public Geometry getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Geometry location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to outdated documentation. The correct documentation for your version is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial).

Hibernate Spatial doesn't support H2, but it does support [GeoDB](https://github.com/jdeolive/geodb) which is based on H2. You might have more luck with that database.

Comment: They are ways around that as shown in this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607183/how-to-configure-spring-boot-project-to-work-with-inmemory-spatial-database-for

Answer (score 1):

In my case, just changing the `hibernate.dialect` to `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.h2geodb.GeoDBDialect`fix it. (according to v 5.2 hibernate docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial))