# H2 Gis: Function "WITHIN" not found

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, gis, h2

I have an integration test running h2, where I try to use jpa criteria to make spatial searches.

The test initializes h2 gis as required in the [documentation](https://github.com/orbisgis/h2gis):

```
@DataJpaTest
@Sql(scripts = "/sql/h2_gis_initialization.sql")
class LocalizationRepositoryTest {
```

Where the sql file contains the following line:

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS H2GIS_SPATIAL FOR "org.h2gis.functions.factory.H2GISFunctions.load"; CALL H2GIS_SPATIAL();
```

When running the test:

```
@Test
void it_can_search_within_geometry() {
    final Polygon polygon = new GeometryFactory().createPolygon();
    List<Localization> results = repository.findAll(
            (root, query, builder) -> JTSSpatialPredicates.within(builder, root.get(Localization_.geometry),
                    polygon));

    Assertions.assertEquals(0, results.size());
}
```

The test fail with the following error:

> ```
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare
> statement     at
> my.api.LocalizationRepositoryTest.it_can_search_within_geometry(LocalizationRepositoryTest.java:66)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not
> prepare statement     at
> my.api.LocalizationRepositoryTest.it_can_search_within_geometry(LocalizationRepositoryTest.java:66)
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:  Function "WITHIN" not found;
> SQL statement: select localizati0_.id as id1_48_,
> localizati0_.spatial_geometry as spatial_2_48_ from localization_t
> localizati0_ where within(localizati0_.spatial_geometry, ?)=?
> [90022-197]   at
> my.api.LocalizationRepositoryTest.it_can_search_within_geometry(LocalizationRepositoryTest.java:66)
> ```

For some reason, the criteria tries to make use of a non-existing spatial function. Why is that? How can I make my test work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this other similar question: [How to configure spring-boot project to work with inmemory spatial database for tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607183/how-to-configure-spring-boot-project-to-work-with-inmemory-spatial-database-for)

It appears that I was just missing the dialect configuration for jpa for tests:

[image]