# Spring Boot + JPA : JPA seems to auto create tables but not sure where

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am practicing/learning some Spring Boot + JPA application and keep running into issues when attempting to save to database table.

It seems JPA is auto generating table name, even though I have provided the @Table annotation.

I have a simple POJO , marked with @Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SongList")
public class SongList {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String album;
    private String artist;
    private String title;

//Getter and Setter Methods 
}
```

An Interface that extends JPA CrudRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface songRepo extends CrudRepository<SongList,Integer> {
}
```

A properties yml file that sets datasource properties

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url :  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Songdb
    username : root
    password : learning

jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto : update
    generate-ddl  : false
    show-sql : true
```

And finally Test class :

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class DataJpaApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    void saveSongs() {

        songRepo repo = (songRepo) context.getBean(songRepo.class);

        SongList songs = new SongList();
        songs.setId(4);
        songs.setTitle("High Hopes");
        songs.setAlbum("Panic! At the Disco");

        repo.save(songs);

    }

}
```

Upon running the Test class , my test fails with error :

```
ERROR:
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'songdb.song_list' doesn't exist
```

My database table already exists. The database is called Songdb (not songdb) and table is SongList.

I am not sure where is the table name 'song_list' being injected and why my database name is 'songdb' instead of 'Songdb' as provided in the url.

What am I missing here ? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are using the default naming strategy provided by Spring boot. Hibernate maps field names using a physical strategy and an implicit strategy. Hibernate uses the Physical Naming Strategy to map our logical names to a SQL table and its columns. Spring Boot, provides defaults for both these strategies `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` defaults to org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy, and
`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy` defaults to org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy

The default naming strategy for spring-boot will :

- Replace dots with underscores
- Change camel case to snake case
- Lower-case table name

You can change it by setting the property like :

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

For you just changing the physical naming strategy will fix your issue. You could also use `org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy` which will keep the table name as it is provided. Now that you know the cause for the issue , you can fix it ay way you like.

You could customize the physical naming strategy like you want incase you want more control. Read : [Hibernate naming strategy changing table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162976/hibernate-naming-strategy-changing-table-names)

Comment: Thank you so much @Ananthapadmandabham for that detailed explaination!