# jpa hibernate mysql query broken

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I have a confusing error with my Spring-boot-JPA-Hibernate classes.

I used the JPA Dali tools to create the Entity classes from my SQL Schema.
While using them (with Spring-boot-jpa / hibarnate) I have some strange problems with unmatched queries. 
Here is one example:

Properties:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="n_user")
@NamedQuery(name="NUser.findAll", query="SELECT n FROM NUser n")
public class NUser implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String imageUrl1;

    private String name_first;


    public NCaterer() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getImageUrl1() {
        return this.imageUrl1;
    }

    public void setImageUrl1(String imageUrl1) {
        this.imageUrl1 = imageUrl1;
    }

    public String getName_first() {
        return this.name_first;
    }

    public void setName_first(String name_first) {
        this.name_first = name_first;
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<NUser, Long> {

}
```

But Hibernate creates this query of it:

```
Hibernate:
    /* select
        generatedAlias0
    from
        NUser as generatedAlias0 */ select
            nuser0_.id as id1_0_,
            nuser0_.image_url1 as image_ur2_0_,
            nuser0_.name_first as name_firs3_0_
        from
            n_user nuser0_
```

The Problem here is the **image_url1** it should be **imageurl1** as described in the Entity class. This happens on several points.

Why do Hibernate transform CamelCase getters into camel_case in the query? And how can I config it not to do it?

Comment: As suggested below, you can put column names and try. Put exception if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify column name by your own use `@Column` annotation for your fields.

Example:

```
@Column(name = "imageUrl1")
private String imageUrl1;
@Column(name = "nameFirst")
private String name_first;
```

Comment: NamedQuery are written for java Pojo names not table names. His query is right for the `NUser` part.

Comment: @yogidilip sorry, fixed

Comment: Thanks alot. That helps pretty straight forward :)

Comment: ADD: The @Column(name ...) have to be in lowercase only, else they will be ignored too.
e.g.: @Column(name = "imageurl1")

Comment: @GregorSklorz where have you found this information? Usually sql is case insensitive and it should don't matter for the db

Comment: @solomkinmv I found it by my own. I tried it in CamelCase and it was ignored completly by Hibarnate. In lowercase it works great.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there have been many people experiencing the same problem in different circumstances. Maybe go and have a look at the different naming strategies below:

[Naming Strategy One](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/)

[Naming Strategy Two](http://sudhirmongia.blogspot.co.za/2010/08/naming-strategy-in-hibernate.html)

[Naming Strategy Three](https://code.google.com/archive/p/hibernate-naming-strategy-for-oracle/source)

You can however change the configuration of your hibernation. Have a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) for further help with regards to that. Or, go and have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437202/improvednamingstrategy-no-longer-working-in-hibernate-5) and see how someone changed it using the above methods.

Comment: yes, I already found some of that too. Thanks, dont know why I had problems finding it in the first way. 
Thanks!