# Spring + Hibernate - issue with @Table name annotation

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I am stuck on strange issue with Spring + Hibernate.

I have some entity:

```
package arthur.khusnutdinov.mysitev2.pub.mods.db;
// Generated 05.09.2017 23:23:19 by Hibernate Tools 5.2.5.Final

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * SitePages generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "site_pages", catalog = "artfunpw")
public class SitePages implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String pageUrl;
    private String pageHtmlContent;
```

And session configuration code:

```
@Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dbDataSource);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        props.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", "/ehcache.xml");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("arthur.khusnutdinov");

        return factoryBean;
    }
```

Everything works fine, untill table name in MySQL database is **sitepages**, but it doesn't work, if table name is **site_pages** - I've got java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'artfunpw.sitepages' doesn't exist .
It seems, like Hibernate is ignoring `@Table(name = "site_pages", catalog = "artfunpw")`.

What am I doing wrong, how to make Hibernate to respect @Table annotation?

Thank you very much!

**Update 1**:
Tried to add

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

into the **application.properties** - didn't helped.

`hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy` is not solved issue too.

**Update 2**: I use hibernate 5 :).

Comment: and what if you ignore `catalog` ?? Also you could try `MySQL5Dialog`

Comment: both variants did not solve the issue

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` is not helped

Comment: `<prop key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">legacy-jpa</prop>` is not helped too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was in changes in Hibernate 5. I found a very useful answer here - [ImprovedNamingStrategy no longer working in Hibernate 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437202/improvednamingstrategy-no-longer-working-in-hibernate-5) .

After I found that answer, I've changed my `sessionFactory()` - I added `factoryBean.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl());` - code:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dbDataSource);

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

    props.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName", "/ehcache.xml");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
    factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);

    factoryBean.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl());

    return factoryBean;
}
```

I also changed code of the `select` statement. Now it looks like

```
List<SitePages> filmList = new ArrayList<>(); 

filmList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createNativeQuery("select * from site_pages")
        .setCacheable(false)
        .list();

System.out.println(filmList.size());
```

After these changes everything works fine :).

Comment: 1) then it is duplicate 2) if you change your select then you changed nothing and @Table may still not work.