# Can i write my table name for the entities in the application.yml?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entity

I am trying to set the name of my tables in the entities using parameters from the `application.yml`

This is the `entity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "${database.tableName}")
public class enitityName {...}
```

And this would be the `application.yml`:

```
database:
    tableName: entityName
```

This doesn't work to me. Is there any way to achieve this?
Can someone give me some ideas?

I need to do it because i have the tables for my differents enviroments in the same database, so the name of the tables are like these: `table_test`, `table`. And they would be the same `class` in my code

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The reason I am asking is to propose potential workarounds, because I believe doing exactly what you ask is not possible.

Comment: I need to do it because i have the tables for my differents enviroments in the same database, so the name of the tables are like these: `table_test`, `table`. And they would be the same `class` in my code

Comment: If Hibernate is your underyling JPA provider, it can use naming strategies for tables. From a quick search, these are relevant: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313095/jpa-hibernate-and-custom-table-prefixes), [link2](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot).

Comment: Sweet, i will try to find a solution using the naming strategies, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible.However, I found a similar problem your question, you can check from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148172/table-name-configured-with-external-properties-file).