# Spring Boot: Change the attribute for @Table in Entity class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parameter-passing

I have on spring boot app having one entity class which is linked to my database table also I used sequence on that table.

So I use Table annotation as well as SequenceGenerator annotation on my Entity class with hard-coded value, like this:

```
@Entity
@Primary
@Table(name = "tbl_name", schema = "public")
//@Table(name = "tbl_name_dev", schema = "public")
public class PoJoClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "tbl_name_id_seq", sequenceName = "tbl_name_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "tbl_name_id_seq")

    // PoJo attributes
    // Setter/Getter

}
```

Which I wanted to implement in way where I can set both the table and sequence as parameter for each profile like dev and prod. As for testing we have table name different then prod in some cases.

Also, I used the same table name in my repository class with @Query annotation, which look like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1 <> ?1", nativeQuery = true)
PoJoClass getLatestRecordForCompositeKey(String col1);
```

Finding out same way to set both as parameter on each profile base.

Update:
Alex, route me to follow this link. And I checked and tried implementing the same in my code but I might not understand that logic due to that it is failing or nothing which I did not get properly. Cloud anyone please help on this.

I wanted to use property: from my application property file and i added the same there.

As that link suggested added the Configuration class.

```
@Configuration 
public class TableNameConfig {

    @Value("${config.table.name}")
    private String configTableName;

    @Value("${visits.table.name}")
    private String visitsTableName;

    @Bean
    public PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl physicalNamingStrategyStandard(){
        return new PhysicalNamingImpl();
    }
    class PhysicalNamingImpl extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

        @Override
        public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
            switch (name.getText()) {
                case "PoJoClass":
                    return new Identifier(configTableName, name.isQuoted());
                case "Visits":
                    return new Identifier(visitsTableName, name.isQuoted());
                case "Result":
                default:
                    return super.toPhysicalTableName(name, context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that I can later use the property like this:

```
@Table(name = "${config.table.name}", schema = "public")
```

But I am getting this error, I think I am not able to resolve that property, not understood where to change and what:

> 2019-12-07 15:57:46.649  INFO 21840 --- [  restartedMain]
>   org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type
>   registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous :
>   org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@233cf9c7 Hibernate: create table
>   public.${config.table.name} (id serial not null, active_flag
>   varchar(255), updated_datetime TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, primary
>   key (id))
>
> 2019-12-07 15:57:50.561  WARN 21840 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget
>   encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create
>   table public.${config.table.name} (id serial not null, active_flag
>   varchar(255), updated_datetime TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, primary
>   key (id))" via JDBC Statement
>
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
>   executing DDL "create table public.${config.table.name} (id serial not
>   null, active_flag varchar(255), updated_datetime TIMESTAMP WITHOUT
>   TIME ZONE, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement  at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
>   [spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   [spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
>   [spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>   [spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   [spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
>   [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
>   [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
>   [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>   [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   [spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]    at
>   com.slb.dataplatform.configurationapi.ConfigurationApiApplication.main(ConfigurationApiApplication.java:12)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE] Caused by:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" 
>   Position: 21  at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2476)
>   ~[postgresql-42.1.1.jar:42.1.1]   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2189)
>   ~[postgresql-42.1.1.jar:42.1.1]   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
>   ~[postgresql-42.1.1.jar:42.1.1]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
>   ~[postgresql-42.1.1.jar:42.1.1]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
>   ~[postgresql-42.1.1.jar:42.1.1]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
>   ~[postgresql-42.1.1.jar:42.1.1]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
>   ~[postgresql-42.1.1.jar:42.1.1]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)
>   ~[postgresql-42.1.1.jar:42.1.1]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:260)
>   ~[postgresql-42.1.1.jar:42.1.1]   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]  at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]  at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]   ... 39 common frames
>   omitted

I think I am not able to override method toPhysicalTableName properly, please let me know what is wrong I did.

Help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148172/table-name-configured-with-external-properties-file

Comment: @Alex I tried with given example and  think he has was solving the same problem which I have but I am not getting why my program is showing error, I am updating my question with code change after your suggestion.

Comment: I see that hibernate complains about `id` type missmatch - `java.util.UUID` vs `org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType`. 

Can you show more `PoJoClass` code, what are the attributes of this class and their types?