# @Table name configured with properties file

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I build a Spring-Boot application that accesses a Database and extracts data from it.  I want to configure the table names from an external .properties file. (Dev and Prod database has different table names)

like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "${entity.table.name}")
public class Entity {
...
}
```

I find this [Table name configured with external properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148172/table-name-configured-with-external-properties-file)

But dont understand how use it? what i should add in properies file?

Comment: as stated in link you provided, it will not work out of the box and you have to use custom SpringNamingStrategy .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table name configured with external properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148172/table-name-configured-with-external-properties-file)