# How to make Spring Data JPA by default naming from camelCase to snake_case unless explicitly specified?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, naming

By default, my Spring Boot project had JPA mapping entity properties to table columns by transforming the names from camelCase to snake_case (e.g. from `fooBar` to `foo_bar`).

I'm working on an existing DB, where the entity property names were kept as is for the table column names (e.g. from `fooBar` to `fooBar`), so I tried to use the `@Column` annotation to explicitly specify the name:

```java
@Column(name = "fooBar")
private String fooBar;
```

This wasn't working. I followed the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38875123/1225328):

```text
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

My `@Column` is now successfully taken into account, but I'm losing the camelCase to snake_case implicit transformation on the properties that don't have the `@Column` the annotation.

Any idea how to transform from camelCase to snake_case by default, unless explicitly specified in the `@Column` annotation?

Comment: @YCF_L MySQL. As I said, `@Column` is now working successfully, but the implicit transformation is not to snake_case anymore.

Comment: Yes I understand, just curious why you want to be like that ?

Comment: @YCF_L Well I think snake_case is more common for SQL entities (kind of unofficial conventions), so the new entities I'm adding should be snake_cased, but I still need to deal with legacy tables that don't follow this convention. We'll rename the existing tables in a second phase.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the default JPA behavior of converting to snake case was not working when I injected my custom spring datasource beans for my H2 and postgres repositories. I wanted to convert camel case to snake case by default without explicitly annotating columns while saving objects to DB. Hence adding below property in application.properties worked for me:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
```

Note: I am using spring boot version 2.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Automatically transforming property-Names using camelCase (as is the naming convention in Java) to SNAKE_CASE seems to be no longer supported as of Hibernate 5. However, you can write your own Implementation of a NamingStrategy, doing exactly that.
Please check [this Stackoverflow-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34565182/7454999) to see how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this in your application.properties file**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

Hier is the source.
[link of tutoriel](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot)